# Is there a way to change the Jinja2 template loading directory per-request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to change the Jinja2 root directory per-request on Flask? Right now I do:

```
app.jinja_loader = FileSystemLoader(template_directory)
```

but it seems to work only once per process (the process chooses the correct directory at first and then stays there, no matter how many changes I make)...

Comment: With some more investigation, it looks like Jinja caches the template in memory, but I don't know where it is. If I change the uptodate function in the source to always return False, it always reloads the template and works.

Comment: Setting cache_size to 0 doesn't work, however...

Comment: Setting cache_size to 0 in the jinja source works, but I can't get it to work when setting the option from Flask, I must be doing it wrongly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that a Jinja caching bug is preventing the correct template from loading, so disabling the cache works:

```
app.jinja_env.cache = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
app._get_current_object().jinja_loader = FileSystemLoader(template_directory)
```

Docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#notes-on-proxies or http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/local/#werkzeug.local.LocalProxy._get_current_object

Comment: That won't work, it says that the app object doesn't have that attribute, which is weird. However, I think I know why that's happening, I'll comment above.